# Adding char to int in Swift

Tags: swift

In Obj-C, I was generating random figures by adding a random value between 0 and 25 to the character "A":

```
'A' + arc4random() % 26
```

In swift, the only way I found to do this is the following

```
func +(left: Character, right: Int) -> Character {
    let oldCharUnicodeScalars = String(left).unicodeScalars

    let newCharIntRepresentation = 
           Int(oldCharUnicodeScalars[oldCharUnicodeScalars.startIndex].value) + right

    return Character("\(UnicodeScalar(newCharIntRepresentation))")
}

let rndChar = String(Character("A") + Int(arc4random()%26))
```

I was wondering if there was something simpler and more flexible.

Comment: what is your ultimate goal? Do you just want a random character between A-Z?

Comment: @cmyr I'm interested in your possible solution, but also in a better implementation of the proposed problem.

Comment: @cmyr On my opinion, he wants a simpler solution which does the same (generates random char in [A-Z]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of a few things to create a one-liner similar to your original solution (I wouldn't really call this more flexible though):

```
var rndChar = String(UnicodeScalar("A".utf16[0] + Int(arc4random_uniform(26))))
```

The `utf16` property of `String` returns a [`UTF16View`](http://swifter.natecook.com/type/String.UTF16View/) which you can then index with an `Int` (`0`) to get the `UInt16` representation of the first character (in this case, the only character, `"A"`). You then add your random number between `0` and `25` to it, pass that to the constructor for `UnicodeScalar` and pass that `UnicodeScalar` to a `String` constructor... whew.

Another method, if you're just looking for a random character between `"A"` and `"Z"`, would be to create an `Array` from a `String` of the characters you want and just grab a random item out of that `Array`:

```
var rndChar = Array("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")[Int(arc4random_uniform(26))]
```

***Sidenote:** I'd recommend using `arc4random_uniform(26)` instead of `arc4random() % 26` as it'll give a more consistently random number:*

> `arc4random_uniform()` will return a uniformly distributed random number less than upper_bound.  `arc4random_uniform()` is recommended over constructions like `arc4random() % upper_bound` as it avoids "modulo bias" when the upper bound is not a power of two.

Comment: Thanks, the one-liner was what I was looking for. Also didn't know that I could index a UTF16View with a simple Integer index (rather than a UnicodeScalarIndex).

Comment: Yeah, UTF16View was a nice find while digging through the generated headers :)

Answer (score 1):

For today Swift doesn't provide simple way to adding `String` to `Int`.

What about this way:

```
func getArrayfromAToZ() -> [String] {
    var charList = [String]()
    for char in 0x41...0x5A { //ascii from 'A' to 'Z'
        charList += [String(UnicodeScalar(char))]
    }
    return charList // ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", .... "Z"]
}

let a = getArrayfromAToZ()[Int(arc4random_uniform(26))] // 'T', ... , 'W'
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe nicer than mine, but Mike S's one-line is better. Btw, voted up your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a less safe but nicer looking rewrite of your own operator overload method:

```
func +(left: String, right: UInt32) -> Character {
    let oldCharUnicodeScalars = String(left).unicodeScalars

    let newCharIntRepresentation =
    Int(oldCharUnicodeScalars[oldCharUnicodeScalars.startIndex].value) + right

    return Character("\(UnicodeScalar(newCharIntRepresentation))")
}
```

`"A" + arc4random()%26` Works nicely

`"AA" + arc4random()%26` This is when unexpected happen!

Comment: Not sure where the difference is, apart from that the first argument is a string (not a plus point, since it opens to unexpected behaviors as you pointed out).